# Python for Excel: While value in column A is the same, take remaining row data and copy paste to new worksheet

Tags: python, excel, loops, openpyxl

I am somewhat of a beginner to python and have encountered the following problem working with openpyxl. For example I have the sample worksheet below: [Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbcrv.png)

What I am trying to do is loop through the Boat ID column and while the values of the cell are the equivalent I want to take the respective row data to the right and open a new worksheet/workbook and copy paste rows in Col B:E.

So in theory, for every Boat ID = 1 we would take every row unique to ID 1 from Cols B:E open a new workbook and paste them accordingly. Next, for every Boat ID = 2 we would take the rows 5-8 in cols B:E, open a new workbook and paste accordingly. Similarly, we would repeat the process for every Boat ID = 3.

P.S. To keep it simple I have ordered the table by Boat ID in ascending order, but if someone wants bonus points they could opine on how it would be done if the table was not ordered.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with openpyxl, but this is relatively simple with pandas, I would definitely check it out.

Loading the sheet is as easy as:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("path_to_file")
```

You can then filter the table by doing something like:

```
 for i in range(df['Boat Id'].max):
    temp_df = df.loc[df[‘Boat ID’]==i]
    temp_df.to_excel(f”path_to_save_location/sheet_{i}.xlsx”)
```

This doesn't handle for duplicate rows with the same boat id, but should get you most of the way!

I would also highly recommend the jupyter notebook extension for prototyping stuff in pandas

Comment: Thanks! One more thing, instead of creating the entire workbook as a dataframe lets say there were multiple sheets in the workbook. How would you create the first sheet as a dataframe?

Comment: It's `pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")`, not `pd.read_xlsx("data.xlsx")`. This method has a parameter `sheet_name=0`. I.e. by default, it reads the first sheet into a DataFrame. Check the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) on how to refer to a different sheet by name, or to get a dictionary of DataFrames for multiple sheets.